# Not getting complete text while Animation on Canvas : Android,

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I want to get an animated text in Android where it should run from left to right on the screen. 
Eg.
I want to get this text
private static final String QUOTE =
            "Nobody uses Java anymore. It's this big heavyweight ball and chain.";

running from right to left using animation.

However, this text gets truncated to  "Nobody uses Java anymore. It's" in Portrait mode and to
"Nobody uses Java anymore. It's this big heavyweight" in landscape mode.

This is the code that I have used

```
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        private static final String QUOTE =
        "Nobody uses Java anymore. It's this big heavyweight ball and chain."; 
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        int len= QUOTE.length();
        canvas.scale(1,-1);
        canvas.drawText(QUOTE, 0, len-1, 100, 60, paint);
        canvas.drawText(QUOTE,0,100 , paint);
        createAnim(canvas);


            private void createAnim(Canvas canvas) {

        anim2= new TranslateAnimation(500,-500,30,30);
        anim2.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim2.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        anim2.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        anim2.setDuration(1000L);
        startAnimation(anim2);

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to do Text Animations using Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181596/how-to-do-text-animations-using-android-sdk)

Please refer this post for text animations.

Comment: The example is fine but I need to do it on Canvas. thanks a lot for the example though

Answer (score 0):

Please check height and width of canvas ,

```
// Custom Font Text
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),
                    (int) getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                            .getHeight() / 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(150);
            Typeface chops = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                    "WC_Speed_Bold_Bta.ttf");
            paint.setTypeface(chops);
            int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
            int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint
                    .ascent()) / 2));
            canvas.drawText("Hello", xPos, yPos, paint);
```